# Is there a single word that means: doing something bad in the name of something good?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: "The burnings at the salem witch trials are an example of _______."

Comment: ..example of *misguided self-righteousness* is what you meant? I'll lokk for a single word then.

Comment: I don't know any single word for this. A common proverb used to describe this idea is ["the end justifies/the ends justify the means."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/end-justifies-the-means--the)
People also use the phrase "a necessary evil" to describe something bad that is supposed to ultimately serve "the greater good."

Comment: Fanaticism, or one of [it's synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fanaticism).

Comment: [Monomania](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/monomania) almost fits.

Comment: And, of course, "zealotry".  (It should be noted that nothing "good" was done in the Salem craziness.  Rather, some very bogus pseudo-religious superstitions were harnessed to do nothing but bad.)

Comment: It strikes me as a matter of opinion (being reliant on the notion that religion, in general, is "something good"), but 'religionism' might work for you: "The burnings at the Salem witch trials are an example of *religionism*." 'Religionism' means "Excessive inclination to religion; marked or affected religious zeal." (*OED Online*)

Comment: One might note that [demonology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demonology) was arguably responsible for the Salem phenomenon.  (And interestingly, it's impossible to demonize someone until you establish an assumption that demons exist.)

Comment: To reiterate:  The Salem trials were not "in the name of something good".  Rather, they occurred because some people convinced other people that demons were at work in the community.  There were, of course, the mandatory contrived references to religious "principles", but more so there were simply references to ancient superstitions (which apparently held sway over much of the community).

Comment: Related or dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204458/a-word-for-something-that-is-immoral-but-beneficial

Answer (score 2):

[**Consequentialism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism)

> Noun
>
> "Consequentialism is the class of normative ethical theories holding that the consequences of one's conduct are the ultimate basis for any judgment about the rightness or wrongness of that conduct." Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

[crusade](https://www.google.com/search?q=crusade%20definition&oq=crusade%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1203j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8):

> lead or take part in an energetic and organized campaign concerning a social, political, or religious issue. –Google

[inquisition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquisition):

> an investigation that violates the privacy or rights of individuals, especially through rigorous or harsh interrogation. –TFD

"The burnings at the Salem witch trials are an example of a(n) [crusade/inquisition] (against heresy)."

Note, both of these words came to mind before I even read the context, which I feel makes them even more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The actually is a word for that, I just forgot the correct spelling, but its got like 3 syllables, goes like: I-pi-kea or I-pi-kia (nvm the spelling).

Comment: Found it. The word is epikeia

Comment: You should edit the word from you comment into your answer (and include a dictionary definition).